# How To Read Health (In Game) Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am looking for a way for python to read the health, in text format, and then execute a command (e.i. press of a key). 
     I was looking at a series by the youtuber sentdex: (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeETZEOy4VdocT7TOjfSA8a). 
     He programmed python to capture his screen and "read" the lanes in order to accomplish a self driving car. 
     I want to base off my goal from the first part of the series, using numpy, PIL, and OpenCV, to capture my screen using the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time



last_time = time.time()
while(True):
    screen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0, 1360, 768)))
    printscreen_numpy =   np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(),dtype='uint8')

    print('Loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
    last_time = time.time()
    cv2.imshow('window', cv2.cvtColor (screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

(Code to print how long it takes a loop can be ignored)

However,  I have no idea how to use opencv or PIL to recognize text in the specified area of my screen, or what to do after to execute a command.

All I need is some advice, not looking for a complete answer.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If area have always the same coordinates on screen you can crop it and crop all of the digits. The digits should be crop very accurate. 
If you want to read only digits (0-9) you can use for example template matching algorithm. For this algorithm digits should look excatly the same on every frame.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html You have to create reference image for all of digits and just look for it on croped image.

Second solution: You can use opencv+tesseract(which includes a highly accurate deep learning-based model for text recognition.). https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/

Other solutions is to get shape of digits (or letters) with threshold, color range in HSV color space (if digits have always the same color) or some other algorithm. Then every digit You can divide on seven segments (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display). Then check for every digit if those segments are empty or fill.
These algorithm is based on pyImageSearch tutorial (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/)